# AccessibilityNodeInfo values

Tags: accessibilityservice

I have been looking at some sample code and I came across a value where you would normally put the action, can someone explain this to me? I have checked the android site, but I couldn't find anything that pointed out values.

```
  I can't find a reference to 16 or 4.
  node.performAction(16);
  node.performAction(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using random integers, these refer to things, but using the integers does not help!

```
node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SELECT);
```

and

```
node.performAction(4);
```

Are literally identical at run time. But one is much more readable code.

```
node.performAction(16)
```

Is nothing meaningful and should be avoided at all costs! There is no AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_...... that is equivalent to 16. I imagine that it wouldn't do anything bad, it would just never do anything productive.